# Can not stage files to be committed

Tags: git

I have a repo on my local machine and on Bitbucket. I cannot see the files that are third party libraries from github I have pushed up there in my repository on Bitbucket as source files, but only a non-clickable folder icon. And when I clone the repo again to a different location I don't get the files in those folders but only the empty folders. No problem with the code files I have written.

I add them on my local repo with `git add` but I cannot see them in `get status` as files to be committed but as changes not staged for commit.
For example I have

```
Macqueena:otp faruk$ git add --all server/src/github.com/gorilla/mux
Macqueena:otp faruk$ git status
# On branch gradesinner
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   scripts.sh
#   deleted:    server/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/gorilla/pat.a
#   deleted:    server/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/gorilla/schema.a
#   deleted:    server/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/gorilla/websocket.a
#   deleted:    server/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx.a
#   deleted:    server/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/reflectx.a
#   deleted:    server/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/justinas/nosurf.a
#   new file:   server/src/github.com/user/createdbandtables/createdb.sql
#   renamed:    server/src/github.com/user/createdbandtables/createdbandtables.sql -> server/src/github.com/user/createdbandtables/createtables.sql
#   new file:   server/src/github.com/user/createsampledata/createsampledata.sql
#   modified:   server/src/github.com/user/main/otp.go
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   server/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (modified content)
#
Macqueena:otp faruk$
```

What is the point in my git workflow I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the directory only (none of the files).

Try this `git add -A server/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/`  Note the trailing slash?  That specifies the **contents** of the directory.

Comment: Git says -a is an unknown switch. Without it worked for this dir only. Other dirs wait solution. Strange.

Comment: The CAPITALIZATION of the 'A' is important.

Comment: after all this time, thanks. However, I need t ask a little meta here: since I ahev long tme ago finished with this project and don have the set up of the time to reproduce the case and validate your answer. However, it seems a quick check answer for any project. Hopefully I will come to this after checking validity on another git repo I work with. regards Thom